# При импорте данных с одной бд в другую возникает ошибка

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу импортировать данные с одной бд в другую(использую sql server express 2017) но при импорте возникает ошибка, импорт провожу в большое количество таблиц (около 2000)

```
Validating (Error)
    Messages
    Error 0xc0202048: Data Flow Task 100: Attempting insertion into the row version column "_Version". Cannot insert into a row version column.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
     
    Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 100: Column metadata validation failed.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
     
    Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 100: "Destination 495 - _Document228" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
     
    Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 100: One or more component failed validation.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
     
    Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 100: There were errors during task validation.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, Вы пытаетесь вставить в явном виде данные в колонку типа rowversion, что невозможно, т.к. rowversion формируются автоматически в базе данных и являются уникальными.
Подробнее здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
Варианты решения: не переносить данные из колонок типа rowversion либо, если обязательно нужно сохранить их значения, колонку в таблице-приёмнике сделать с типом binary(8)

Comment: А есть какой то способ что бы пачкой отключить этот столбец ?

Comment: В мастере импорта я не знаю, как отключить сразу по нескольким таблицам. Можно отключить у каждой таблицы отдельно, если открыть настройки  маппинга и там поставить ignore у нужной колонки.

Comment: Можно попробовать в мастере импорта в самом конце выбрать не Run Immediatly, а Save SSIS Package -> File System, тогда будет создан ssis-пакет, в котором помимо потоков данных будет сгенерирован скрипт создания таблиц-приёмников. Можно отредактировать этот скрипт и заменить в нём тип данных rv на binary(8) (потом перелить данные этим пакетом либо мастером импорта в уже созданные таблицы) либо же отредактировать xml-представление самого пакета, где для всех колонок rv в таблицах приёмниках отключить заполнение и перелить данные этим пакетом.